# how could I post feed like tetris battle or glassdoor using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, api, feed

what I mean is...

in facebook timeline mode,

tetris battle and glassdoor, those 2 fb apps post feed on the right hand side as picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb19P.jpg

is it an original feed post?

how could I use api to post feed like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is the right answer
but maybe it's a "meta tags" game, I mean facebook has multiple meta tags that you could add to your website and facebook uses to classify pages when it scrapes the web, check out step 2 in this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
there's for example a tag that specifies the type of the page

and song is one of the allowed values (that maybe SoundCloud is using for it's pages)

Answer (score 0):

> is it an original feed post?

No, these are most likely Aggregations of Open Graph actions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/aggregations/